# Creating javaroles in Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oraclexe

I have installed Oracle 11g Express Edition in my system.I want to create user who has got the role javauserpriv.
After creating the user I ran the following command 
grant javauserpriv to dbuser(new user) and I got the below error.

QL Error: ORA-01919: role 'JAVAUSERPRIV' does not exist
01919. 00000 -  "role '%s' does not exist"
*Cause:    Role by that name does not exist.
*Action:   Verify you are using the correct role name.

I ran the following query to check all roles

select * from DBA_ROLES

I got the following roles 
ROLE                           PASSWORD_REQUIRED AUTHENTICATION_TYPE

---

CONNECT                        NO                NONE
RESOURCE                       NO                NONE
DBA                            NO                NONE
SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE            NO                NONE
EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE           NO                NONE
DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE            NO                NONE
EXP_FULL_DATABASE              NO                NONE
IMP_FULL_DATABASE              NO                NONE
LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR         NO                NONE
DBFS_ROLE                      NO                NONE
AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE          NO                NONE
AQ_USER_ROLE                   NO                NONE
DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE     NO                NONE
DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE     NO                NONE
ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK      NO                NONE
GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS       NO                NONE
XDB_WEBSERVICES_OVER_HTTP      NO                NONE
RECOVERY_CATALOG_OWNER         NO                NONE
SCHEDULER_ADMIN                NO                NONE
HS_ADMIN_SELECT_ROLE           NO                NONE
HS_ADMIN_EXECUTE_ROLE          NO                NONE
HS_ADMIN_ROLE                  NO                NONE
OEM_ADVISOR                    NO                NONE
OEM_MONITOR                    NO                NONE
PLUSTRACE                      NO                NONE
CTXAPP                         NO                NONE
XDBADMIN                       NO                NONE
XDB_SET_INVOKER                NO                NONE
AUTHENTICATEDUSER              NO                NONE
XDB_WEBSERVICES                NO                NONE
XDB_WEBSERVICES_WITH_PUBLIC    NO                NONE
APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE        NO                NONE

How do I create java roles in Oracle so that I can give the new user access to the roles,sepcifically javauserpriv.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the role by executiung `CREATE ROLE` statement but anyway XE does NOT support Java stored procedures.